# Testing accuracy higher than training accuracy

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

Why is the testing accuracy higher than my training accuracy? This is not the case for the validation accuracy. Is it because of the way I am splitting my dataset?

Modifying the network did not work so I am guessing I am doing something wrong in the dataset preparation part.

The dataset is composed of packet captures of malware and normal activities.. dataset.txt file contains total of 777 rows and 28 columns.

```
#converting dataset and labels to numpy arrays
x = np.genfromtxt("dataset.txt", delimiter=",")
y = np.genfromtxt("label.txt", delimiter=",")

#handling missing values
x[np.isnan(x)] = 0

#shuffling the data
indices = np.arange(x.shape[0])
np.random.shuffle(indices)
x = x[indices]
y = y[indices]

#dividing the dataset into train and test 
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

#building the model
def build_model():
        model = models.Sequential()
        model.add(layers.Dense(32, activation='relu', input_shape=(28,)))
        model.add(layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
        model.add(layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dropout(0.2))
        model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
        model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',  loss='binary_crossentropy', 
                      metrics=['accuracy'])
        return model

'''cross validation 
k = 5
num_val_samples = len(x_train) // k
all_scores = []

for i in range(k):
   print('fold #', i)
   x_val = x_train[i * num_val_samples: (i + 1) * num_val_samples]
   y_val = y_train[i * num_val_samples: (i + 1) * num_val_samples]
   partial_x_train = np.concatenate([x_train[:i * num_val_samples], 
                     x_train[(i + 1) * num_val_samples:]], axis=0)
   partial_y_train = np.concatenate([y_train[:i * num_val_samples], 
                     y_train[(i + 1) * num_val_samples:]], axis=0)
   model = build_model()
   model.fit(partial_x_train, partial_y_train,epochs=20, batch_size=16, 
             verbose=0)
   val_loss, val_acc = model.evaluate(x_val, y_val, verbose=0)
   all_scores.append(val_acc)

print(all_scores)
val_acc = np.mean(all_scores)
print(val_loss , val_acc) 
'''

#training the model with the entire training dataset
model = build_model()
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=16)

#confusion matrix
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
y_pred = (y_pred > 0.5)
result = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
print ('Confusion Matrix:')
print(result)

#calculating the test accuracy
model_acc = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
print('Test Accuracy:')
print(model_acc)
```

Comment: Not really enough information to know for sure, but testing accuracy *can* be higher than training accuracy. If all of your data is independent and you sample randomly, then your test accuracy can come out better than training by chance. If your test set is somehow coupled to your training set (some dependency in the data that the network encodes), then this isn't even that uncommon, but in that case you may not be testing generalization accuracy like you think you are.

Comment: How big are your datasets? If quite small, try splitting them differently, e.g. another random seed. If it then doesn't happen anymore, your datasets are too small and it was just a coincidence. The bigger the datasets the less likely such coincidences occur.

Comment: Is your Dropout function properly treating the test separate from the train process? If it was Keras's, then it does. At 20% drop rate, I wouldn't expect too much of a boost, but still likely one. Try running model.predict on (x_train) and test the accuracy.

Comment: The dataset is composed of packet captures of malware and normal activities.. dataset.txt file contains total of 777 rows and 28 columns.  So there is no way to avoid this from happening uless I increase the size of my dataset?

Answer (score 3):

This is because keras reports running average accuracy for each epoch. For small number of epochs this means that by the *end* of an epoch your model is better than it was on average *during* this epoch.

This could also be due to randomly having 'easier' samples in the test set, but this would not happen each run if you split it randomly in the same portion of the code.